# Check the entered value in textboxes are double number in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am very new to WPF world so do not have much ideas about doing it. Basically,
I want to check whether value entered into textboxes are double number or not.If the value is double number then change the result textbox value to `NAN` and also change the color of input textbox to red.

Can anyone please guide me how to accomplish this?

Model.cs

```
  public abstract class ObservableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public void Set<TValue>(ref TValue field, TValue newValue, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (!EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default.Equals(field, default(TValue)) && field.Equals(newValue)) return;
            field = newValue;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }


    public abstract class ViewModelBase : ObservableBase
    {
        public bool IsInDesignMode
            => (bool)DesignerProperties.IsInDesignModeProperty
                .GetMetadata(typeof(DependencyObject))
                .DefaultValue;
    }
```

ViewModel.cs

```
 public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            if (IsInDesignMode)
            {
                valueA = 2;
                valueB = 3;
                Calc();
            }
        }

        #region Properties

        private int valueA;
        public int ValueA
        {
            get => valueA;
            set
            {
                Set(ref valueA, value);
                Calc();
            }
        }

        private int valueB;
        public int ValueB
        {
            get => valueB;
            set
            {
                Set(ref valueB, value);
                Calc();
            }
        }

        private int valueC;
        public int ValueC
        {
            get => valueC;
            set => Set(ref valueC, value);
        }

        private int valueD;
        public int ValueD
        {
            get => valueD;
            set => Set(ref valueD, value);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        private void Calc()
        {
            ValueC = valueA + valueB;
            ValueD = valueA * valueB;
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WPFTestApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFTestApplication.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="1"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Silver" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="TextBoxA" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBox}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="TextBoxB" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBox}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBox}"/>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <TextBlock Text="Value A"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ValueA, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"

                 Style="{StaticResource TextBoxA}"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Value B" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ValueB, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"

                 Style="{StaticResource TextBoxB}"

                 Grid.Row="1"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Value C" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ValueC}"

                 IsReadOnly="True"

                 Grid.Row="2"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Value D" Grid.Row="3"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ValueD}"

                 IsReadOnly="True"

                 Grid.Row="3"/>


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified your code to achieve your goal:

Model.cs

I have added ObservableBase.NotifyPropertyChanged()

```
     public abstract class ObservableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public void Set<TValue>(ref TValue field, TValue newValue, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
            {
                if (!EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default.Equals(field, default(TValue)) && field.Equals(newValue)) return;
                field = newValue;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }


        public abstract class ViewModelBase : ObservableBase
        {
            public bool IsInDesignMode
                => (bool)DesignerProperties.IsInDesignModeProperty
                    .GetMetadata(typeof(DependencyObject))
                    .DefaultValue;
        }
```

Then your ViewModel would look like this, you see I changed the types from int to string, then added validation flags, the trick to check whether the input is double or not is to use double.TryParse.

```
 public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            valueAisValid = true;
            valueBisValid = true;
            if (IsInDesignMode)
            {
                Calc();
            }
        }

        #region Properties

        private string valueA;
        public string ValueA
        {
            get => valueA;
            set
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    Set(ref valueA, value);
                    Set(ref valueAisValid, double.TryParse(ValueA, out double d));
                    NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(ValueAIsValid));
                    Calc();
                }
            }
        }

        private bool valueAisValid;
        public bool ValueAIsValid => valueAisValid;

        private string valueB;
        public string ValueB
        {
            get => valueB;
            set
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    Set(ref valueB, value);
                    Set(ref valueBisValid, double.TryParse(ValueB, out double d));
                    NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(ValueBIsValid));
                    Calc();
                }
            }
        }

        private bool valueBisValid;
        public bool ValueBIsValid => valueBisValid;

        private string valueC;
        public string ValueC
        {
            get => valueC;
            set => Set(ref valueC, value);
        }

        private string valueD;
        public string ValueD
        {
            get => valueD;
            set => Set(ref valueD, value);
        }

        public bool InputsValid => ValueAIsValid && ValueBIsValid;

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        private void Calc()
        {
            if (InputsValid)
            {
                double sum = Convert.ToDouble(valueA) + Convert.ToDouble(valueB);
                double product = Convert.ToDouble(valueA) * Convert.ToDouble(valueB);
                ValueC = sum.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                ValueD = product.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            else
            {
                ValueC = "NAN";
                ValueD = "NAN";
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Now here is the new guy, meet BoolToBackgroundColorConverter.

```
namespace WPFTestApplication
{
    public class BoolToBackgroundColorConverter: IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null && !(bool)value)
            {
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            }
            else if(value != null && (bool)value && parameter != null)
            {
                return (SolidColorBrush)parameter;
            }
            else
            {
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Now your xaml would look like:

```
<Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:BoolToBackgroundColorConverter x:Key="BoolToBackgroundColorConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightGreen" Color="LightGreen" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightBlue" Color="LightBlue" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="White" Color="White" />
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="1"/>
            </Style>
             <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="TextBoxA" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding ValueAIsValid, Converter={StaticResource BoolToBackgroundColorConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource LightBlue}}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding ValueAIsValid, Converter={StaticResource BoolToBackgroundColorConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource White}}" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="TextBoxB" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding ValueBIsValid, Converter={StaticResource BoolToBackgroundColorConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource LightGreen}}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding ValueBIsValid, Converter={StaticResource BoolToBackgroundColorConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource White}}" />
        </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBox}"/>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <TextBlock Text="Value A"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ValueA, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"

                 Style="{StaticResource TextBoxA}"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Value B" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ValueB, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"

                 Style="{StaticResource TextBoxB}"

                 Grid.Row="1"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Value C" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ValueC}"

                 IsReadOnly="True"

                 Grid.Row="2"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Value D" Grid.Row="3"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ValueD}"

                 IsReadOnly="True"

                 Grid.Row="3"/>


    </Grid>
```

Output:

[image]
[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: shall i place `BoolToBackgroundColorConverter` inside folder. Currently, it is showing error `does not exist in the namespace xmlns:local1="clr-namespace:WPFTestApplication"`

Comment: you need to wrap the coverter inside your WPFTestApplication namespace. See edits.

Comment: small doubt, as when i load the page, textbox A and textbox B in already filled with color. But I want only when mouse cursor enters.

Comment: I see, but that's a rather weird behavior, what happens if you hover to other fields, the background of your previously hovered field will become white. Anyway, you can still wrap the style inside the trigger.

Comment: I edited the xaml with the behavior that you wanted also added a behavior when you hovered to other fields the invalid field would still have the red background and will be white if it's valid but the desired mouseover effect is still there.

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again. If I want to change text color to Gray for textbox C and D then how can I accomplish that. Please help me. Currently, It is showing white.

Comment: In TextBox C and D  xaml add a property to specify the background: Background="Gray"

Comment: Can you please check [this] and help me out (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52244189/how-to-change-main-window-color-when-textbox-input-changes-in-wpf-application)

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way for your problem is to implement a `ValidationRule`.

Here is the code for the rule:

```
public class DoubleValidation : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        //You can do whatever you want here
        double check;
        if (!double.TryParse(value.ToString(),out check))
        {
            //ValidationResult(false,*) => in error
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Please enter a number");
        }
        //ValidationResult(true,*) => is ok
        return new ValidationResult(true, null);
    }
}
```

Then in your XAML you have to refer to this `ValidationRule` when binding, which allows you to get the `Validation.HasError` property in your style.

```
<TextBox Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="ValueB" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:DoubleValidation/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBoxB}" TargetType="TextBox">
              <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Since the `Error` will add a red border to the `TextBox`, I add `Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}"` to keep full control.

If you want to change the `Textbox` value to `NaN`, you should do it in your `ViewModel`. But I would disrecommend that, since it's very boring for the user to see its inputs getting change by the UI.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to handle the validation in the View layer - using a control such as DoubleUpDown from the [Extended WPF Toolkit](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit), rather than trying to validate in the ViewModel by parsing a text string.