# How to change main window color when textbox input changes in WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to change main window color when  textbox input changes in WPF application. Currently, when mouse hover or enters the textbox color changes but I will remove this as I do not want this effect. But I want the same effect when mouse cursor enters into textboxes, it should change main back ground colors.

MainWindow background color is:

- LightBlue, when mouse cursor enters A inputbox
- LightGreen, when mouse cursor enters B inputbox
- LightGray,all other cases.

Model.cs

```
public abstract class ObservableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public void Set<TValue>(ref TValue field, TValue newValue, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (!EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default.Equals(field, default(TValue)) && field.Equals(newValue)) return;
        field = newValue;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}


public abstract class ViewModelBase : ObservableBase
{
    public bool IsInDesignMode
        => (bool)DesignerProperties.IsInDesignModeProperty
            .GetMetadata(typeof(DependencyObject))
            .DefaultValue;
}
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
 public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            valueAisValid = true;
            valueBisValid = true;
            if (IsInDesignMode)
            {
                Calc();
            }
        }

        #region Properties

        private string valueA;
        public string ValueA
        {
            get => valueA;
            set
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    Set(ref valueA, value);
                    Set(ref valueAisValid, double.TryParse(ValueA, out double d));
                    NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(ValueAIsValid));
                    Calc();
                }
            }
        }

        private bool valueAisValid;
        public bool ValueAIsValid => valueAisValid;

        private string valueB;
        public string ValueB
        {
            get => valueB;
            set
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    Set(ref valueB, value);
                    Set(ref valueBisValid, double.TryParse(ValueB, out double d));
                    NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(ValueBIsValid));
                    Calc();
                }
            }
        }

        private bool valueBisValid;
        public bool ValueBIsValid => valueBisValid;

        private string valueC;
        public string ValueC
        {
            get => valueC;
            set => Set(ref valueC, value);
        }

        private string valueD;
        public string ValueD
        {
            get => valueD;
            set => Set(ref valueD, value);
        }

        public bool InputsValid => ValueAIsValid && ValueBIsValid;

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        private void Calc()
        {
            if (InputsValid)
            {
                double sum = Convert.ToDouble(valueA) + Convert.ToDouble(valueB);
                double product = Convert.ToDouble(valueA) * Convert.ToDouble(valueB);
                ValueC = sum.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                ValueD = product.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            else
            {
                ValueC = "NAN";
                ValueD = "NAN";
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

BoolToBackgroundColorConverter

```
   public class BoolToBackgroundColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null && !(bool)value)
            {
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            }
            else if (value != null && (bool)value && parameter != null)
            {
                return (SolidColorBrush)parameter;
            }
            else
            {
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            }
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WPFTestApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFTestApplication.ViewModel"
        xmlns:local1="clr-namespace:WPFTestApplication"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <local1:BoolToBackgroundColorConverter x:Key="BoolToBackgroundColorConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightGreen" Color="LightGreen" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightBlue" Color="LightBlue" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="white" Color="white" />
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="1"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="TextBoxA" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBox}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding ValueAIsValid, Converter={StaticResource BoolToBackgroundColorConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource LightBlue}}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding ValueAIsValid, Converter={StaticResource BoolToBackgroundColorConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource white}}" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="TextBoxB" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBox}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding ValueBIsValid, Converter={StaticResource BoolToBackgroundColorConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource LightGreen}}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding ValueBIsValid, Converter={StaticResource BoolToBackgroundColorConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource white}}" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBox}"/>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <TextBlock Text="Value A"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ValueA, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"

                 Style="{StaticResource TextBoxA}"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Value B" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ValueB, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"

                 Style="{StaticResource TextBoxB}"

                 Grid.Row="1"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Value C" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ValueC}"


                 IsReadOnly="True"

                 Grid.Row="2"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Value D" Grid.Row="3"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ValueD}"

                 IsReadOnly="True"

                 Grid.Row="3"/>


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AttachCustomBehaviors();
        }

        // There's a better way of doing this, read attached behavior in wpf
        private void AttachCustomBehaviors()
        {
            TextBoxA.GotFocus += (s, args) => ChangeMainWindowBackground(this, Brushes.LightBlue);
            TextBoxB.GotFocus += (s, args) => ChangeMainWindowBackground(this, Brushes.LightGreen);
            TextBoxA.LostFocus += (s, args) => ChangeMainWindowBackground(this, Brushes.Gray);
            TextBoxB.LostFocus += (s, args) => ChangeMainWindowBackground(this, Brushes.Gray);
        }

        private void InputFieldsHovered(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!TextBoxA.IsFocused && !TextBoxB.IsFocused)
            {
                ChangeMainWindowBackground(this, Brushes.Gray);
            }
            else if(TextBoxA.IsFocused)
            {
                ChangeMainWindowBackground(this, Brushes.LightBlue);
            }
            else if (TextBoxB.IsFocused)
            {
                ChangeMainWindowBackground(this, Brushes.LightGreen);
            }
        }

        private static void ChangeMainWindowBackground(Window window, SolidColorBrush color)
        {
            window.Background = color;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the updated xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        Background="Gray">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:BoolToBackgroundColorConverter x:Key="BoolToBackgroundColorConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="White" Color="White" />
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="1"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="TextBoxA" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBox}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding ValueAIsValid, Converter={StaticResource BoolToBackgroundColorConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource White}}" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="TextBoxB" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBox}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding ValueBIsValid, Converter={StaticResource BoolToBackgroundColorConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource White}}" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBox}"/>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <TextBlock Text="Value A"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxA" Text="{Binding ValueA, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxA}" MouseEnter="InputFieldsHovered"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Value B" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxB" Text="{Binding ValueB, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxB}" Grid.Row="1" MouseEnter="InputFieldsHovered"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Value C" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxC" Text="{Binding ValueC}" IsReadOnly="True" Background="Gray" Grid.Row="2" MouseEnter="InputFieldsHovered"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Value D" Grid.Row="3"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxD" Text="{Binding ValueD}" Background="Gray" IsReadOnly="True" Grid.Row="3" MouseEnter="InputFieldsHovered"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Your ViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            valueAisValid = true;
            valueBisValid = true;
        }

        #region Properties

        private string valueA;
        public string ValueA
        {
            get => valueA;
            set
            {
                Set(ref valueA, value);
                Set(ref valueAisValid, double.TryParse(ValueA, out double d));
                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(ValueAIsValid));
                Calc();
            }
        }

        private bool valueAisValid;
        public bool ValueAIsValid => valueAisValid;

        private string valueB;
        public string ValueB
        {
            get => valueB;
            set
            {
                Set(ref valueB, value);
                Set(ref valueBisValid, double.TryParse(ValueB, out double d));
                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(ValueBIsValid));
                Calc();
            }
        }

        private bool valueBisValid;
        public bool ValueBIsValid => valueBisValid;

        private string valueC;
        public string ValueC
        {
            get => valueC;
            set => Set(ref valueC, value);
        }

        private string valueD;
        public string ValueD
        {
            get => valueD;
            set => Set(ref valueD, value);
        }

        public bool InputsValid => ValueAIsValid && ValueBIsValid;

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        private void Calc()
        {
            if (InputsValid)
            {
                double sum = Convert.ToDouble(valueA) + Convert.ToDouble(valueB);
                double product = Convert.ToDouble(valueA) * Convert.ToDouble(valueB);
                ValueC = sum.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                ValueD = product.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            else
            {
                ValueC = "NAN";
                ValueD = "NAN";
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: so shall i remove the model class? If so then how can I acheive when user enters double value then only textbox value should change to red.

Comment: Actually I also have to consider this scenario like When user type into the A or B input textbox and it is not a double number, make that input
box red and show C = "NaN" and D = "NaN". Also update C and D when typing.

Comment: Here everything should still work as is, we just added additional behavior for windows background. VMl is still helpful for input validation, do you want to remove the light blue and light green color on textbox a and texbox b?

Comment: Yes Mac. How to do this. Should I change anything in class code for this.

Comment: Appreciated if you could provide complete solution for this.

Comment: Updated your code, the textboxes would turn to red when you hover the mouse to it (same behavior).

Comment: This is working but at the same time I want to textbox red  when cursor enters. So basically, it should do on mouse hover as well as mouse click.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you many times. I want to remove mouse hover and want to implement only cursor click. Can you please invite me on chat if possible from your end then.

Comment: I made an update, see if that fits your requirements.

Comment: Now mouse cursor click issues got resolved. Can you please update small changes as well. Now I have to implement mousehover. If I mouse hover any where in form or in the textbox, still it should show main window Gray. I hope I am not irritating you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179701/discussion-between-frame-and-mac).

Answer (score 3):

I have modified your source code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BoolToBackgroundColorConverter x:Key="BoolToBackgroundColorConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid Background="{Binding BackgroundColor}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightGreen" Color="LightGreen" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightBlue" Color="LightBlue" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightGray" Color="LightGray" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="White" Color="White" />
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="1"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
                <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource White}" />-->
            </Style>                
        </Grid.Resources>

        <TextBlock Text="Value A"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ValueA, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter" >
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseEnterCommand}" CommandParameter="{StaticResource LightBlue}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave" >
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseLeaveCommand}" CommandParameter="{StaticResource White}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </TextBox>

        <TextBlock Text="Value B" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ValueB, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="1">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter" >
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseEnterCommand}" CommandParameter="{StaticResource LightGreen}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave" >
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseLeaveCommand}" CommandParameter="{StaticResource White}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </TextBox>

        <TextBlock Text="Value C" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ValueC}"                 Grid.Row="2">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter" >
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseEnterCommand}" CommandParameter="{StaticResource LightGray}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave" >
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseLeaveCommand}" CommandParameter="{StaticResource White}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </TextBox>

        <TextBlock Text="Value D" Grid.Row="3"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ValueD}"                 Grid.Row="3">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter" >
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseEnterCommand}" CommandParameter="{StaticResource LightGray}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave" >
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseLeaveCommand}" CommandParameter="{StaticResource White}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </TextBox>

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ICommand MouseEnterCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand MouseLeaveCommand { get; set; }
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            valueAisValid = true;
            valueBisValid = true;
            MouseEnterCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(MouseEnterCommandHandler);
            MouseLeaveCommand =new  RelayCommand<object>(MouseLeaveCommandHandler);
            if (IsInDesignMode)
            {
                Calc();
            }
        }

        #region Properties

        private string _backgroundColor;
        public string BackgroundColor
        {
            get { return _backgroundColor; }
            set { _backgroundColor = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(BackgroundColor)); }
        }


        private string valueA;
        public string ValueA
        {
            get { return valueA; }
            set
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    double d;
                    Set(ref valueA, value);
                    Set(ref valueAisValid, double.TryParse(ValueA, out d));
                    NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(ValueAIsValid));
                    Calc();
                }
            }
        }

        private bool valueAisValid;
        public bool ValueAIsValid => valueAisValid;

        private string valueB;
        public string ValueB
        {
            get { return valueB; }
            set
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    double d;
                    Set(ref valueB, value);
                    Set(ref valueBisValid, double.TryParse(ValueB, out d));
                    NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(ValueBIsValid));
                    Calc();
                }
            }
        }

        private bool valueBisValid;
        public bool ValueBIsValid => valueBisValid;

        private string valueC;
        public string ValueC
        {
            get { return valueC; }
            set { Set(ref valueC, value); }
        }

        private string valueD;
        public string ValueD
        {
            get { return valueD; }
            set { Set(ref valueD, value); }
        }

        public bool InputsValid => ValueAIsValid && ValueBIsValid;

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        private void Calc()
        {
            if (InputsValid)
            {
                double sum = Convert.ToDouble(valueA) + Convert.ToDouble(valueB);
                double product = Convert.ToDouble(valueA) * Convert.ToDouble(valueB);
                ValueC = sum.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                ValueD = product.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            else
            {
                ValueC = "NAN";
                ValueD = "NAN";
            }
        }

        private void MouseEnterCommandHandler(object parameter)
        {
            if (parameter != null)
            {
                BackgroundColor = parameter.ToString();
            }
        }

        private void MouseLeaveCommandHandler(object parameter)
        {
            if (parameter !=null)
            {
                BackgroundColor = parameter.ToString();
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Please add System.Windows.Interactivity dll to the project and Create a RelayCommand class inheriting ICommand interface.